# Using timer to capture webcam images

Tags: python, opencv, time, computer-vision

How do I get breaks during the image capture? In fact, I need 5sec in between the image.

This code captures around 15-20 images per sec, But I need to take a picture at an interval of 5sec in between images

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(3,640)
capture.set(4,480)
img_counter = 0
frame_set = []
start_time = time.time()

while(True):
    ret , frame = capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame_set.append(gray)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed = end_time - start_time
    img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name,frame)
    print("{} written!".format(img_counter))
    img_counter +=1
    if elapsed > 1:

        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: what do you mean in between images?

Comment: You could understand better if you run that script...

Comment: @Sandeep I think OP means take an image in every five sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an if statement to check if the desired time has passed. Using the already imported time package you can do this:

```
import cv2
import time

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(3, 640)
capture.set(4, 480)
img_counter = 0
frame_set = []
start_time = time.time()

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if time.time() - start_time >= 5: #<---- Check if 5 sec passed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_counter))
        start_time = time.time()
    img_counter += 1
```

The above script will save the frame in RGB every 5 seconds to the working directory.

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: @christoffer  That's perfect ! The script runs endlessly right ? Yeah ! Suppose I need to terminate the script after a time period ( i.e like after 5 hours ) What shall i do to break it or terminate it ?

Comment: @Sai You can use a similar `if` statement with a new time variable and set the condition to 18000 (18000 seconds = 5 hours). Just put a `break` in the statement if fulfilled and you should be good.